# Converting MPG to AVI with using ffmpeg.exe in C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I have a problem converting an MPG file to an AVI file. When I converted a file, for example 520KB MPG file, my program generated an AVI file of about 112MB and that video does not work properly.  What would cause this?

```
     string path = "C:\\convert\\input.mpg" 
     string outputpath = "C:\\convert\\"+output+".avi";

     string fileargs = "-i" + " " + path + "  " + outputpath;


        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\convert\\ffmpeg.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();


        p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Try to read command line switches with examples and you'll figure out something.  BTW, your problem has nothing to do with c#, your code is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for Quicktime rewrapping. Not sure it will work as fine on AVI but you could have a go.

```
fileargs = String.Format("-i {0} -vcodec copy -acodec copy {1}", path, outputpath);
```

or, if that doesn't work, you could try:

```
fileargs = String.Format("-i {0} -vcodec copy -acodec pcm_s16le {1}", path, outputpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg has ***many*** options. It will probably take some experimentation to get the correct settings.